# Why isn't __new__ in Python new-style classes a class method?

Tags: python, new-operator, language-design, new-style-class

The Changelog for Python 2.2 (where new-style classes were introduced) says the following about the `__new__` function:

> `__new__` is a static method, not a class method. I initially thought it would have to be a class method, and that's why I added the `classmethod` primitive. Unfortunately, with class methods, upcalls don't work right in this case, so I had to make it a static method with an explicit class as its first argument.

However, I cannot think of why class methods wouldn't work for this purpose, and it would certainly look better. Why didn't `__new__` end up as a class method in the end? What does Guido refer to when he says that "upcalls don't work right in this case"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`__new__` being static method allows a use-case when you create an instance of a subclass in it:

```
return super(<currentclass>, cls).__new__(subcls, *args, **kwargs)
```

If `new` is a class method then the above is written as:

```
return super(<currentclass>, cls).new(*args, **kwargs)
```

and there is no place to put `subcls`.

> I don't really see when that would be a proper use of `__new__`, though. Maybe I'm not seeing it, but that just seems to me to be a completely pathological use of it (and it should be said, that if you still really want it, then you could access it with `object.__new__.__func__`). At the very least, I find it very hard to imagine that it would have been the reason for Guido to change `__new__` from being a class method to a static method.

A more common case would be to call parent `__new__` without using `super()`. [You need a place to pass `cls` explicitly in this case](http://ideone.com/JdzTI):

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        print("Base.new(%r)" % (cls,))
        return cls()

class UseSuper(Base):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        print("UseSuper.new(%r)" % (cls,))
        return super(UseSuper, cls).new() # passes cls as the first arg

class NoSuper(Base):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        print("NoSuper.new(%r)" % (cls,))
        return Base.new()  # passes Base as the first arg

class UseFunc(Base):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        print("UseFunc.new(%r)" % (cls,))
        return Base.new.im_func(cls)  # or `.__func__(cls)`. # passes cls as the first arg

print(UseSuper.new())
print('-'*60)
print(NoSuper.new())
print('-'*60)
print(UseFunc.new())
```

Comment: @Duncan: I've intentionally used `new` rather than `__new__`. If it is unclear, leave a comment I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: I think if you had used a name that was a bit more distinct than just dropping the underscores it would have been clearer, but I understand now thanks.

Comment: When would this actually be a problem, though? If you want an instance of `subcls`, why wouldn't you call `subcls.new()`? Doing it the way you describe only has the effect of not running the proper `__new__` functions on `subcls`.

Comment: @Dolda2000: the point is that it creates a subclass instance *using code from a parent `__new__()`*. And `__new__` being a `@classmethod` would complicate that. I can't think of a real use case from the top of my head when you need it i.e., you've called [`Base()` but got `Derived()`](http://ideone.com/YJ0eW). If you exclude subclasses of immutable types then overriding `__new__` is an esoteric language feature (like metaclasses) that might be useful in equally esoteric cases.

Comment: I don't really see when that would be a proper use of `__new__`, though. Maybe I'm not seeing it, but that just seems to me to be a completely pathological use of it (and it should be said, that if you still really want it, then you _could_ access it with `object.__new__.__func__`). At the very least, I find it very hard to imagine that it would have been the reason for Guido to change `__new__` from being a class method to a static method.

Comment: @Dolda2000: A more common case would be to call parent `__new__` without using `super()`. [You need a place to pass `cls` explicitly in this case](http://ideone.com/JdzTI).

Comment: Your last comment seems to me to be the very reason why BDFL decided to make `__new__` a static method (not a class method).

Comment: That's a good point. I can see how that could be the actual reason, yes.

Comment: @jfs I miss read a previous comment and responded. I’ve deleted the comment.

Comment: @jfs: I can not understand the example you gave: can __new__() be rewritten without preceding and trailing double underscores? .. and why do that at first place? (you said you could elaborate, please do) Thanks

Comment: @Searcherer: if you need to pass a subclass to the super method, then no (without hacks).

Comment: @jfs: .. I can't relate. In your suggested example, you define new(), not __new__(), is this acceptable? Isn't Python expecting __new__(), not new()?

Comment: @Searcherer: no. `new()` and `__new__` are completely different methods. "new" here is an ordinary class method (it could have been any name e.g., "new_method_to_illustrate_some_point_in_the_answer" <-- method name). `__new__` is magic (static) method -- it must be called `__new__`.

Comment: @jfs: Thank you.

Comment: "A more common case would be to call parent __new__ without using super()"  Why is this a "more common case"?  This seems simply incorrect.  You have no way of knowing that "Base" is your parent class.  You must call super.

Comment: @NeilG: "more common" is relative to the "use-case when you create an instance of a subclass in it." Note: the question is about the decision in Python 2.2 The answer uses Python 2. You can use super with static methods there but it may be surprising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788214/super-and-staticmethod-interaction

Comment: @jfs I don't see why he couldn't have made it a class method with the additional class parameter to indicate which class should be constructed.  This would have solved all of the problems, I think.