# Python: Why would float.__new__(cls) work when cls isn't float?

Tags: python

I'm a little confused by the following example from the python documentation [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__).

```
>>> class inch(float):
...     "Convert from inch to meter"
...     def __new__(cls, arg=0.0):
...         return float.__new__(cls, arg*0.0254)
...
>>> print inch(12)
0.3048
>>>
```

Presumably, float is here is the actual float class defined somewhere deep inside Python. When we call `float.__new__(cls, argument)` , we're sneakily calling the function that returns instances of float for a given argument, but we're passing it the inch class instead of the float class. Since the inch class doesn't really do anything, why does this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `inch` is a *subclass* of float, it satisfies all the requirements that the `float.__new__()` instance factory has. It is the job of the [`__new__(cls)` static method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) to create instances of the first argument, not of it's 'own' class.

Note the word 'static method' there. The `__new__` factory is really just a specialist function tied to a class only for inheritance reasons. In other words, it is a function that plays well in a object-oriented hierarchy. You are supposed to find it via `super()` or perhaps call it directly (as done here). The following would actually be a little more pythonic:

```
def __new__(cls, arg=0.0):
    return super(inch, cls).__new__(cls, arg*0.0254)
```

because that would call the 'correct' `__new__` function if `inch` were to be used in a multiple-inheritance hierarchy; in this simple example it'll end up calling `float.__new__` just the same.

So, `__new__(cls, ...)` is expected to create an instance of type `cls`. Why then tie it to a class at all and not make it a more generic function then? Because in the case of `float.__new__(cls, value)` it not only creates a new instance of type `cls`, it also sets it's initial value to `value`. And in order for that to work, `float.__new__(...)` needs to have intimate knowledge of what the `float` class looks like. Because `inch()` is a subclass of `float()`, it has the exact same necessary bits to be a `float()` too, and thus when the `float.__new__()` factory creates a new `inch` instance, all those bits are there to make it a `inch()` instance instead.

Comment: Fantastic! This makes so much more sense now. So, to make sure I understand now - __new__ is a static method, which is to say it has no interest in (and no argument for) 'self'. When I overwrite it for this particular class, it presumably stays static (since one could hardly have a __new__ method that required an instance). How does python know to do this without any decorators?

Comment: Because `__new__` is special. It is automatically a static method, see the documentation I linked in my answer.

Comment: `__new__` is double special. It could have been a classmethod. The ability to call parent `__new__` without `super()` while passing `cls` in it (e.g., `float.__new__(cls, ..)`) might be the reason [why `__new__` is not a classmethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092072/why-isnt-new-in-python-new-style-classes-a-class-method).

Comment: Aha - right there in the first line: "a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such)". Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

A little background is needed to answer this question:

1. Only `object.__new__()` can create a new `instances` type of objects, this
   kind of objects cannot be subclassed.
2. An instance has a `type`, which can be assigned when passing the type name
   `cls` to `__new__(cls)` as the first argument. `class` keyword creats
   another kind of objects: classes (a.k.a types), and these kinds of objects
   *can* be subclassed.

Now, go back to your example, what

```
float.__new__(cls, argument)
```

essentially does is using `object.__new__(cls)` to create a new instance (`float.__base__` is `object`),
assign the type `cls` (`inch` in this case) to it, and also does something with `argument` defined in `float.__new__`.

So it is not surprising that it'd work when `cls` isn't `float` but `inch`: the class/type is already created by `class inch(float)`, you are just assigning this type to a new instance.