# How to correctly use a float as a base class and define methods for the new class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, base-class

How to perform the below:

```
def to_distance(speed, time):
    return speed * time

speed = 10.0
to_distance(speed, 5)
```

in the context of a class. That is, using a class with a base class of `int` and having a `to_distance` method. The below attempt:

```
class Speed(float):

    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__(n)

    def to_distance(self, n):
        return self * n
```

running:

```
s = Speed(11.0)
```

results in a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4c35f2c0bca9> in <module>
----> 1 s = Speed(11.0)

<ipython-input-17-6baa46f60665> in __init__(self, n)
      2 
      3     def __init__(self, n):
----> 4         super().__init__(n)
      5 
      6     def to_distance(self, n):

TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments
```

Comment: This error is because you called `super.__init__` instead of `super().__init__`. However, you can't pass a value either way. Perhaps just save `self.n = n` in `__init__`?

Comment: @Nathan good pick up, oversight which I corrected, albeit the challenge still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even this seems to work, though I'm a bit confused - maybe somebody with better knowledge of Python internals can chime in?

```py
class Speed(float):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__()

    def to_distance(self, n):
        return self * n

s = Speed(2)
print(s) # 2.0
print(isinstance(s, float)) # True
print(s ** 2) # 4.0
z = s - 2
print(isinstance(z, Speed)) # False
print(isinstance(z, float)) # True
print(s.to_distance(3)) # 6.0
```

EDIT - adding `print(self, n)` to `__init__` gives `2.0 2` when calling `s = Speed(2)`. What I think is happening is that `__new__` has already made `self` into the appropriate value, so `n` isn't needed anymore at `__init__`. Removing `super().__init__()` leads to just the same results above, so we could just have this instead:

```py
class Speed(float):
    def to_distance(self, n):
        return self * n
```

EDIT2 - you might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534461/python-why-would-float-new-cls-work-when-cls-isnt-float).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
class Speed(float):
    def __init__(self, n):
        float.__init__(n)

    def to_distance(self, n):
        return self * n
```

test and output:

```
s = Speed(11.0)
dist = s.to_distance(5)
print(dist)   # output 55.0
```