# super() and @staticmethod interaction

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-methods, super

Is super() not meant to be used with staticmethods?

When I try something like

```
class First(object):
  @staticmethod
  def getlist():
    return ['first']

class Second(First):
  @staticmethod
  def getlist():
    l = super(Second).getlist()
    l.append('second')
    return l

a = Second.getlist()
print a
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asdf.py", line 13, in <module>
    a = Second.getlist()
  File "asdf.py", line 9, in getlist
    l = super(Second).getlist()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getlist'
```

If I change the staticmethods to classmethods and pass the class instance to super(), things work fine. Am I calling super(type) incorrectly here or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: These should be class methods

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The short answer to

> Am I calling super(type) incorrectly here or is there something I'm missing?

is: yes, you're calling it incorrectly... AND (indeed, *because*) there is something you're missing.

But don't feel bad; this is an extremely difficult subject.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) notes that

> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is unbound.

The use case for *unbound* `super` objects is extremely narrow and rare. See these articles by Michele Simionato for his discussion on `super()`:

- [Things to Know About Python Super [1 of 3]](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275)
- [Things to Know About Python Super [2 of 3]](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278) (this one specifically covers unbound super)
- [Things to Know About Python Super [3 of 3]](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=237121)

Also, he argues strongly for removing unbound `super` from Python 3 [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-September/010181.html).

I said you were calling it "incorrectly" (though correctness is largely meaningless without context, and a toy example doesn't give much context). Because unbound `super` is so rare, and possibly just flat-out unjustified, as argued by Simionato, the "correct" way to use `super()` is to provide the second argument.

In your case, the simplest way to make your example work is

```
class First(object):
  @staticmethod
  def getlist():
    return ['first']

class Second(First):
  @staticmethod
  def getlist():
    l = super(Second, Second).getlist()  # note the 2nd argument
    l.append('second')
    return l

a = Second.getlist()
print a
```

If you think it looks funny that way, you're not wrong. But I think what most people are expecting when they see `super(X)` (or hoping for when they try it in their own code) is what Python gives you if you do `super(X, X)`.

Comment: Is this any different in Python 3, where `super()` without any arguments is the usual way to call it in a regular method?  I had the same problem in Python3 when calling `super().foo()`.

Comment: @gerrit: Python 3's zero-argument `super()` only works in class or instance methods. This is due to the magic that it uses to determine which class it's being defined in. Within static methods (just as in regular, module-level functions), you still need two explicit arguments. (The single-argument form is also still unbound in Python 3.)

Comment: God bless you and your family

Answer (score 7):

When you call a normal method on a object instance, the method receives the object instance as first parameter. It can get the class of the object and its parent class, so it makes sense to call `super`.

When you call a class method on an object instance or on a class, the method receives the class as first parameter. It can get the parent class, so it makes sense to call `super`.

But when you call a static method, the method does not receive anything and has no way to know from what object or class it was called. That's the reason why you cannot access `super` in a static method.

Answer (score 3):

Since Second inherits form First, you can just use `First.getlist()` instead of passing in two arguments in super(i.e. `super(Second, Second)`)

```
class First(object):
   @staticmethod
   def getlist():
     return ['first']

class Second(First):
  @staticmethod
  def getlist():
    # l = super(Second, Second).getlist()
    l = First.getlist()
    l.append('second')
    return l

a = Second.getlist()
print (a)
```

Comment: However, this can get screwed up if you later change the ancestry. For example, if an intermediate class `OnePointFive` is added in the inheritance tree in between `First` and `Second`, `Second` will skip a level when calling what used to be its super.