# Why doesn't super() work with static methods other than __new__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods, super

I understand that `__new__` is a static method and `super()` can be called from it create a new object, like so:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __new__(cls):
...         print('__new__ called')
...         return super().__new__(cls)
...
>>> a = A()
__new__ called
```

Why doesn't the `super` call work with other static methods? Why does the following fail?

```
>>> class B:
...     @staticmethod
...     def funcB():
...         print('funcB called')
...
>>> class C(B):
...     @staticmethod
...     def funcC():
...         print('funcC called')
...         super().funcB()
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.funcC()
funcC called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in funcC
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue15753. `super(C, C).funcC()` would work in your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [super() and @staticmethod interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788214/super-and-staticmethod-interaction)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`super()` with no arguments in Python 3 is basically a hack over its argument based version.

When `super()` gets no arguments it fetches the first argument i.e the class using a special cell variable named `__class__` and for second argument it will get the first local variable from the stack(which is going to be function's first argument).

In case of `__new__` it can get both(`__class__` and `cls`) and works fine.

But in this case for example there's no second variable available apart from `__class__` hence it fails.

```
class A:
  @staticmethod
  def func():
    super().func()  # super(__class__, <missing>).func()


A().func()  # RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Now if we change it to accept an argument then things change:

```
class A:
  @staticmethod
  def func(foo):
    super().func()


# This fails because super(B, 1).func() doesn't make sense.
A().func(1)  # TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
# Works! But as there's no parent to this class with func() it fails as expected.
A().func(A())  # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Hence the only solution is to make the things explicit with `super()` in your case:

```
super(C, C).funcC()
```

---

In general I am not sure why the implementation in case of staticmethod can't make an exception and use `__class__` for both the arguments to make it work.

---

Related [CPython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L7434):

```
static int
super_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    superobject *su = (superobject *)self;
    PyTypeObject *type = NULL;
    PyObject *obj = NULL;
    PyTypeObject *obj_type = NULL;

    if (!_PyArg_NoKeywords("super", kwds))
        return -1;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|O!O:super", &PyType_Type, &type, &obj))
        return -1;

    if (type == NULL) {
        /* Call super(), without args -- fill in from __class__
           and first local variable on the stack. */
        PyFrameObject *f;
        PyCodeObject *co;
        Py_ssize_t i, n;
        f = PyThreadState_GET()->frame;
        if (f == NULL) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                            "super(): no current frame");
            return -1;
        }
        co = f->f_code;
        if (co == NULL) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                            "super(): no code object");
            return -1;
        }
        if (co->co_argcount == 0) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                            "super(): no arguments");
            return -1;
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, `super(C, C).funcB()` does work. One thing: when we write `super(type, type2)` then as per the documentation `type2` should be a subclass of `type`. But here both the types are same, i.e. `C`.

Comment: @Deb Every type is a subtype of itself.

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` is treated as a special-case by the python interpreter (pretty much all the "dunder" methods are). One aspect of this special case handling is to make `super` have access to the underlying class object when normally a `staticmethod` does not.  You can search for `__new__` in [the source code for the `type` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c) to take a peek at what is going on under the hood.

To solve what you were trying to do with inheritance, you probably want a `classmethod`.

```
>>> class B:
...     @classmethod
...     def funcB(cls):
...         print('funcB called')
...
>>> class C(B):
...     @classmethod
...     def funcC(cls):
...         print('funcC called')
...         super().funcB()
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.funcC()
funcC called
funcB called
```

Comment: [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is a static method.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I realize that they say static method there, but I wouldn't be surprised if that is a documentation error.  I'm going to dig into that.  It behaves as a class method because it gets the class object passed to it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Looks like you are right... [it's in the C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L2597).  It seems that the reason is because `__new__` treated specially by the interpreter.

Comment: You could simply check it with: `class A: pass; A.__new__(A); A.__new__()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I prefer to read the source to understand what they are doing so I can understand the cause, not the effect.

Comment: I don't remember stopping you. :-|

Answer (score 0):

You are right, but `__new__` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument. Its ideal behavior is somewhat like a **classmethod**.

But when you call a **staticmethod** method, the method does not receive anything, an has no way to know from what object or class it was called. That's the reason why you cannot access super in a **staticmethod**.

Therefore, **new** by definition has a class argument in it and can use super along with it.

For your logic you should make a call to instatiate your object and call the function that you want to call from there.

Comment: `super()` doesn't care about who called a function, `super()` uses `__class__` variable to figure out the class of the current function.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use "classmethod" instead of "staticmethod" for example

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        return "in a"
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print(cls.a())

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        return "in b"

B.foo()
## in b
```