# Inheritance issue creating objects

Tags: python, inheritance

**Person.py**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, pname):
        self.name = pname

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, name):
        return cls(name)
```

**Employee.py**

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, ename, esalary):
        super().__init__(ename)
        self.salary = esalary

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data):
        person = super().parse(data["name"])
        person.salary = data["salary"]
        return person
```

**Customer.py**

```
class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self, ename, country):
        super().__init__(ename)
        self.country = country

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data):
        person = super().parse(data["name"])
        person.country = data["country"]
        return person
```

**main.py**

```
emp_data = {
    "name": "john",
    "salary": 1000
}
emp = Employee.parse(emp_data)
print(type(emp))
print(emp.name)
print(emp.salary)


cust_data = {
    "name": "peter",
    "country": "USA"
}
cust = Customer.parse(cust_data)
print(type(cust))
print(cust.name)
print(cust.country)
```

**errors**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-a5abd51d9870> in <module>()
     36     "salary": 1000
     37 }
---> 38 emp = Employee.parse(emp_data)
     39 print(type(emp))
     40 print(emp.name)

<ipython-input-32-a5abd51d9870> in parse(cls, data)
     14     @classmethod
     15     def parse(cls, data):
---> 16         person = super().parse(data["name"])
     17         person.salary = data["salary"]
     18         return person

<ipython-input-32-a5abd51d9870> in parse(cls, name)
      5     @classmethod
      6     def parse(cls, name):
----> 7         return cls(name)
      8 
      9 class Employee(Person):

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'esalary'
```

This example is just for reproducing the problem in the actual code. The actual parse functions involve complex logic.

In the above example, `Employee` and `Customer` classes extend `Person` class. According to the error, `init` method of `Person` class which is invoked by `parse` form same class, is expecting `esalary`. But there is no `esalary` property on `Person` init method.

What's wrong with my program? I think I did not understand inheritance properly. Please, correct me. First of all, did I structure my program correctly?

Comment: `cls` will be `Employee` not `Person`

Comment: why? could you explain that as an answer?

Comment: @What first argument for what?

Comment: Take a look :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788214/super-and-staticmethod-interaction

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri Im not 100% sure thats why I removed my comment but normally every first argument of a object refers to self. So when you pass cust_data, you actually only pass to self. I don't know the edge-cases however.

Comment: About your program structure, why do you need the parse method? You can pass the data into the `__init__`, it would be simpler, and essentially the same thing.

Comment: @progmatico They mentionned this is a simplified example. In their real code I'm sure they are parsing something much more complicated which doesn't map directly to the init arguments.

Comment: exactly. if I have all those arguments readily available to pass to init, why would i create parse?

Comment: Ok, I see they will want that complex methods to be classmethods, not instance methods or complex `__init__` code, but even then, making `__init__` call the class parse method will make the object instantiation more natural (instantiate with data object argument vs calling parse directly in client code).

Comment: @progmaticoThey may be instantiating the class with just params from other places in the code so they want to keep init straightforward. I think it's a matter of taste whether you want `__init__` to dispatch based on params and/or type inspection or if you want to have multiple public constructor methods.

An alternative would be to always use the constructor and have `parse` set the relevant fields instead of having `parse` create the instance.

Comment: I agree @jbch. And for dispatching based on type there is also funtctools singledispatch decorator, which compensates that absence.

Comment: @jbch Basing on comments about using instance methods, I changed my code https://trinket.io/python/c161df00a4 . In this case, I don't need to init method at all. are there any pros and cons of each of these approaches (class methods vs instance methods). personally, I like to write simple init. so that code reader can easily know what properties that class have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `parse` calls `cls(name)`, which only has one argument, but `cls` is `Employee` or `Customer`, not necessarily `Person`. You must either provide the additional arguments (salary/country) at construction time (when you call `parse`), or give them a default value when they aren't provided.

Either provide the additional needed arguments to the constructor via `parse`:

```
@classmethod
def parse(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
    return cls(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

which would allow you do something like:

```
Employee.parse(name, salary)  # Really no different than Employee(name, salary)
```

Or add defaults to those parameters in the child constructors so that they can be constructed with only a name:

```
class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self, ename, country=None):
        # ...

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, ename, esalary=None):
        # ...
```

Note that this might result in you having `None` values floating around in these attributes, but that's inevitable if you want to construct a new, say, `Employee` object and don't want to also provide a salary at the same time.

Comment: adding *args, **kwargs to Person's parse did not solve the problem

Comment: Question: if cls is Employee, i should call cls(name, salary). what if salary data is not available at that moment. what if i want to initialize salary only after crating employee object?

Comment: Then add default values, like I suggest in the second code block. A reasonable default would be `None`, e.g., `def __init__(self, ename, esalary=None):`

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` only pass on extra arguments that got passed to `parse`. If they didn't get passed to `parse`, then there's nothing to pass on, so the constructor still receives too few parameters. If you're willing to tolerate missing data in these classes, at least briefly, add default values of `None` to these extra parameters in your child classes.

Comment: adding default value `None` solved the problem. Finally, Could you explain in simple terms why cls is Employee here in your answer? is that how inheritance works?

Comment: Yeah, that's what `classmethod` does is give you the type/class on which the method was called. So `Employee.parse` makes `cls=Employee` and `Customer.parse` makes `cls=Customer`. The same `parse` function gets called in either case (it's inherited), but the `cls` argument encapsulates *how* it got called, since that's important in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
class Foo():
    @classmethod
    def p(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)

 class Bar(Foo):
     @classmethod
     def p(cls):
         super().p()

bar = Bar()
bar.p()
```

This will print "Bar". The class object passed to `Foo.p` when called from within `Bar.p` is actually the `Bar` class, not the `Foo` class.

So in your code, when you call `Person.parse` through `Employee.parse`, your line in `Person.parse`, `return cls(name)` is actually calling `Employee(name)`, but `Employee`'s init take 2 positional arguments.

For your code to work with this structure, your `__init__`s have to have the same signature, or at least compatible signatures (for example by adding *args to `Person`'s `__init__` method and passing them to the constructor).