# Why does Super() return TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python

I'm playing about with super function with the following code:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def hello(string):
        print('hello '+string)

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def greeting(string):
        super().hello(string)
        print('How are you?')
x = B
x.greeting('mate')
```

However, the above gives me the following error:
***TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type***

I have looked for other issues related to this on S.O but they don't address this particular question.

Why is this happening? isn't x a subtype of type?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [super() and @staticmethod interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788214/super-and-staticmethod-interaction)

Comment: Also, don't forget to *call* the class constructor when you're trying to create an instance. That is, you probably wanted to type `x = B()` not `x = B`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using super function you can directly give the super function name i.e A. This is because we cann't use self keyword in this case. HOWEVER, if you want to use super() then pass super(B, B).

```
# First alternative
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def hello(string):
        print('hello '+string)

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def greeting(string):
        A.hello(string)
        print('How are you?')
x = B
x.greeting('mate')

# second alternative
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def hello(string):
        print('hello '+string)

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def greeting(string):
        super(B, B).hello(string)
        print('How are you?')
x = B
x.greeting('mate')



#either way, you will get following

output>>>hello mate
How are you?
```